# Error spotting: I have dreamt all my life to own a beautiful maroon-coloured car

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

> I have dreamt all my life to own a beautiful maroon-coloured car.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct?

The solution which I have says **dreamt** is followed by preposition **of** so accordingly correct sentence should be:

> I have dreamt all my life **of** owning a beautiful maroon-coloured car.

Is it correct?

Comment: If the reader knows that "maroon" is a color, the word "coloured" or "colored" is redundant.  (It is still grammatically correct, although many people would hyphenate "maroon-coloured" or "maroon-colored".)

Comment: @Jasper: natural languages allow for redundancy, which reinforces meaning. Redundancy in engineered systems and in information exchange is not a bad thing.

Comment: @Jasper Sorry, it happened because of auto correct of my mobile, didn't notice it. Editing the question.

Comment: Your second version is fine, idiomatic and evocative. The phrase "all my life" is in exactly the right position to modify the verb _dream_. Disregard all the foofaraw and stick with that version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first version

> I have dreamt all my life to own a beautiful maroon coloured car.

is wrong because the verb is "to dream of" not "to dream to." The second version

> I have dreamt all my life of owning a beautiful maroon coloured car.

although more correct, is still clumsy in splitting the verb. I would prefer

> I have dreamt of owning a beautiful maroon coloured car all my life.

Comment: Honestly I prefer "All my life I have dreamt of owning a beautiful maroon coloured car." I don't like having "all my life" at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Minor addition: It should be *maroon-colored* car, with the hyphen.

Comment: @Nayuki or *a beautiful car colored maroon* ?

Comment: @ArthurDent I thought about putting it that way round but this way was my preference. When people say it like that, perhaps would need a comma.

Comment: It depends on the emphasis - `I have dreamt...all my life` feels like "all my life" is the important piece of information; `All my life...a beautiful maroon coloured car` sounds like it is the fact that you've dreamt of a car specifically that is important.

Comment: @FacticiusVir I would say it is exactly the other way round. Starting with *All my life* makes it the more important idea. Putting it at the back introduces the car first, making it irrelevant whether you dreamt of it all of your life, or only recently.

Comment: How about just *maroon car* ?

Comment: I just want to say that the second phrase is completely acceptable, if you add the following commas: "I have dreamt, all my life, of owning a beautiful maroon-colored car".

Comment: @Sven: The second phrase is perfectly correct without commas _(in fact, I'd argue it's better without them)_.  However, splitting the verb makes it sound poetic, which would be slightly unnatural in everyday speech.

Comment: I find your last version very awkward, because "all my life" could refer to how long you will own the car, rather than how long you have had dreams of owning the car. That is, "I have dreamed that I will, for all my life, own...". Of course this parsing is a little silly because we don't think of cars as lasting so long, and therefore the reader can resolve the author's ambiguity. But it's better to write the unambiguous sentence instead: "I have dreamt all my life of owning...", or "All my life I have dreamt...".

Comment: @amalloy nice touch, but that would surely be *I have dreamt of owning a beautiful maroon-colored car **for the rest of my life***.

Comment: ... since you could not own that car for *all* of you life anyway, that is, including the life you had before you bought the car.

Comment: @Nayuki The hyphen is not required here. It is entirely a matter of style and taste. Why do you imagine it is required?

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I think 'cause hyphens indicate pairs of words that are supposed to be understood as one "word", instead of "two", also there might be ambiguity if you don't use it? Like, how "circle-shaped" is a adjective, while "circle shaped", is... something? The latter, I'd use in "The image of a circle shaped my thoughts on minimalist art."

Comment: @Malandy As someone said, it's "a matter of style and taste". Here, there is no danger that anything but the car will be mistakenly perceived as maroon in color (nor in colour). (I would describe something as _circular_ myself, but "circle shaped" would probably be understood. If I were forced to write something so clumsy, I'd probably use a hyphen, as a matter of style and taste.)

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the statement is grammatical, but it doesn't make sense. Using the infinitive *to own* here implies that the goal of dreaming was to own a red car. In other words, it means something like

> 1. I have dreamt all my life *in order* to own a beautiful maroon coloured car.

Instead, to mark the object/subject of the dream, we use *of*:

> 2. I have dreamt all my life **of** owning a beautiful maroon coloured car.

This makes sense.

Naturally, it's possible to use a *to*-infinitive and *of* in the same sentence with the verb *dream*:

> 3. I have dreamt  all my life **of** riches and fame **to** keep my spirits high.

Comment: Your explanation is consistent with the fact that it is correct to say "I have **wanted** all my life **to** own a beautiful maroon-coloured car."

Comment: Isn't "dreaming to own something" the same as "dreaming of owning something"? ... Actually, when you say "dreaming of", I'm more inclined to think a nocturnal dream, instead of wish-type dreams...

Answer (score 5):

The common expression is to dream "of" something.  So the alternative that you provide sounds much more natural to me:

> I have dreamt all my life *of* owning a beautiful maroon coloured car.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's correct, because your proposed correction makes it seem like the dreams that are being discussed are the kind you get when you sleep, instead of the use of **dream** as a synonym for **wish**, because people dream **of** things, in their dreams, while people wish **to** do things.